# How to fix: Sorting method

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

Here is my method that handles sorting an array of strings

```
func bucketNameGenerator(player1Id: String, player2Id: String) -> String { 
    var bucketName : String =  ""
    var uniqueBucketID = [String]()

    uniqueBucketID = [player1Id, player2Id]

    let sortedUniqueBucketID = uniqueBucketID.sorted(by: <)

    bucketName = sortedUniqueBucketID.joined().replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")

    print("[bucketNameGenerator] bucketName: \(bucketName)")

    return String(bucketName)
}
```

The two string values aren't pure strings they contain number values as well. this way of sorting does not return the same value each time. Need suggestions on improvement here / directed down a path to create an asymmetric string each time.

> Example Expected Results:

```
player1Id : 123jinrk1412941jdlndma
player2Id: 49812u4jldanec192hce12n

expected result both combined and sorted in an ascending order :
49812u4jldanec192hce12n123jinrk1412941jdlndma
```

The above example isn't correctly sorted but the goal is to get a string that is the same every-time the method runs with two inputted values.

Comment: Your function *does* return the same value each time for the two player ids, independent of their order. – Please provide input,  expected output, and actual output to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `sorted` for just two items is overkill.

To consider numeric values `compare` the strings with option `numeric`

```
func bucketNameGenerator(player1Id: String, player2Id: String) -> String {
    let result : String
    if player1Id.compare(player2Id, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending {
        result = player1Id + player2Id
    } else {
        result = player2Id + player1Id
    }
    return result.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you intended to use `>` ?

```
func bucketNameGenerator(player1Id: String, player2Id: String) -> String {
    let uniqueBucketID = [player1Id, player2Id]

    let sortedUniqueBucketID = uniqueBucketID.sorted(by: >)

    let bucketName = sortedUniqueBucketID.joined().replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")

    return bucketName
}
```

Or simpler :

```
func bucketNameGenerator(player1Id: String, player2Id: String) -> String {

    let output = player1Id < player2Id ?
    player2Id + player1Id : player1Id + player2Id

    return output.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
}
```